# How to mask out the object from the image?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, masking

I have a RGB image of 256X256 with the binary mask. I want to remove the object from the main image with the help of mask and keep the rest background.

I have tried with the below code but it didn't work.

Can anyone let me know where I made the mistake?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read image
img = cv2.imread('image.jpg')

mask2 = cv2.imread('mask.jpg') / 1
# mask by multiplication, clip to range 0 to 255 and make integer
result2 = (img * mask2).clip(0, 255).astype(np.uint8)



# save results
cv2.imwrite('result.png', result1)
```

Image, Mask:

[image] [image: Mask]

Output I want, The result I am getting:

[image: Output] [image: My result]

Comment: also show the output you did get.

Comment: attached @ChristophRackwitz

Comment: @PScode Are you expecting [this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNgLw.jpg) ?

Comment: Yes @JeruLuke  :)

Comment: Can you please share your code? @JeruLuke

Comment: Do you want to remove those 2 browns and 2 metals?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `cv2.bitwise_and` for your problem. It performs 'AND' operation between your `img` and `mask` in a bitwise manner.

- For white region in the `mask`, corresponding `img` region is preserved
- For white region in the `mask`, corresponding `img` region is occluded

**Code:**

```
img = cv2.imread(r'C:\Users\524316\Desktop\Stack\eye\eye.jpg')
mask = cv2.imread(r'C:\Users\524316\Desktop\Stack\eye\mask.jpg', 0)

# invert the mask
th = cv2.threshold(mask,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# preserve the background
res = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask = th)
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: I have one more question. How to use the same method if I have a pair of tiff file(Image[band 4]+Mask[band 1])? @JeruLuke

Comment: @PScode You can slice them into 2 arrays and follow as above

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Otsu thresholding, just ordinary thresholding, with a sensible threshold. Your "mask" image is a JPEG. Lossy compression causes it to *not* be entirely black or white.

Once you have the mask, you just need to learn about masking operations. That is a feature of `numpy` I'm using here:

```py
im = cv.imread("VgAjK.jpg")
maskim = cv.imread("ZKKkp.jpg", cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

im[maskim >= 128] = 255 # "remove", paint over with white
```

[image: output]

You multiplied... that *might* have worked (except inverted) if your arrays had the right value ranges.